# How do you generate a good ID in ATOM documents?

Tags: atom-feed

Apparently using the URL is no good - why is this the case, and how do you generate a good one?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Mark Pilgrim's article [How to make a good ID in Atom](http://web.archive.org/web/20110514113830/http://diveintomark.org/archives/2004/05/28/howto-atom-id) is good.  Here's part of it:

> **Why you shouldn’t use your permalink as an Atom ID**
>
> It’s valid to use your permalink URL
>   as your <id>, but I discourage it
>   because it can create confusion about
>   which element should be treated as the
>   permalink. Developers who don’t read
>   specs will look at your Atom feed, and
>   they see two identical pieces of
>   information, and they pick one and use
>   it as the permalink, and some of them
>   will pick incorrectly. Then they go to
>   another feed where the two elements
>   are not identical, and they get
>   confused.
>
> In Atom, <link rel="alternate"> is
>   always the permalink of the entry.
>   <id> is always a unique identifier for
>   the entry. Both are required, but they
>   serve different purposes. An entry ID
>   should never change, even if the
>   permalink changes.
>
> “Permalink changes”? Yes, permalinks
>   are not as permanent as you might
>   think. Here’s an example that happened
>   to me. My permalink URLs were
>   automatically generated from the title
>   of my entry, but then I updated an
>   entry and changed the title. Guess
>   what, the “permanent” link just
>   changed! If you’re clever, you can use
>   an HTTP redirect to redirect visitors
>   from the old permalink to the new one
>   (and I did). But you can’t redirect an
>   ID.
>
> The ID of an Atom entry must never
>   change! Ideally, you should generate
>   the ID of an entry once, and store it
>   somewhere. If you’re auto-generating
>   it time after time from data that
>   changes over time, then the entry’s ID
>   will change, which defeats the
>   purpose.

Comment: thanks for the internet archive link - i had linked to his original post a couple of years ago and just found it gone.  then i remembered [Hanselman's Article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/410GoneThoughtsOnMarkDiveintomarkPilgrimsAndWhysInfosuicides.aspx)

Comment: One should note this: "The ID must be globally unique, across all Atom feeds, everywhere, for all time.". I asked myself this very question so some others might as well.

Comment: This answer is a bit focused on what to avoid. So what should we do? Use a [tag URI](http://www.taguri.org/), as specified in [RFC 4151](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4151.html).

Comment: It is idiotic to write a certain code because "developers will get confused". If they don't know what the id tag is, they shouldn't develop.

Comment: The author(s) are talking about Wordpress style permalinks, not real permanent links. Wordpress permalinks are simply "clean urls" which are dynamic. Real permalinks are static, based on entity ID, & don't change unless the entity is deleted. So yes, it is indeed acceptable to use **real** permalinks for `<id>`, and you should def always use them for `rel="alternate"` too.

Answer (score 2):

Use a GUID for the ID.

depends what language you use, but you could use

System.Guid for .NET.

Comment: or java.util.UUID for, um, java

Comment: the more human readable taguri described in the article linked by @cjm can often be more useful.

Comment: One caution for using a GUID would be that the ID should ideally be unique across ALL feeds anywhere.  Though the chance of having a collision would be small it would exist, so prefix it with the site domain or similar to make sure they're unique.